# Cannot disable onclick/onblur values for text field via jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, onblur

## What I have

I have a text field, the mark-up of which I cannot directly edit:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" id="subscribe-field" 
onclick="if ( this.value == 'Email Address' ) { this.value = ''; }" 
onblur="if ( this.value == '' ) { this.value = 'Email Address'; }">
```

## What I need

I need the text field value to be blank regardless of whether the text field is clicked, not clicked or clicked out of.

## What I've tried

I can disable the value:

```
$('#subscribe-field').val('');
```

I've tried to disable the onclick and onblur values:

```
$('#subscribe-field').click(function() { return false; });
$('#subscribe-field').off('click');
$('#subscribe-field').unbind('click');
```

...however, the value reappears as soon as I click outside of the text field.

## My question

How do I remove the onblur value from the above mark-up?

Comment: + 1 for neatly arranged question.

Comment: @OptimusPrime - Acknowledgement appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this way :

`$('#subscribe-field').removeAttr('onclick');`

`$('#subscribe-field').removeAttr('onblur');`

Comment: A jsfiddle to prove it too: http://jsfiddle.net/8pAre/ (I wanted to check it before upvoting)

Comment: @Chris - The live jsfiddle demonstration is useful for future referencing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove inline JavaScript. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9GAv/). Using `jQuery.one` will make sure that focus event will get called only once.

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" id="subscribe-field" />



$('#subscribe-field').one('focus',function() { 
            this.value = ''; 
       return false; 
});
```

UPDATE: As suggested by [mahmoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188954/mahmoud), you should remove onClick and onBlur attribute if you can't edit your html.

`off` and `unbind` will unbind jQuery `click` event not inline  `onclick` and  return false will also would not solve your problem as inline `onClick` will get called first.

Comment: "I have a text field, the mark-up of which I cannot directly edit" so he can't remove the inline javascript.

Comment: @Shusl - Thanks but for some reason that code did not prevent the value from reappearing when clicking outside the text field. Do I need to be using additional jQuery code in conjunction with what you've posted? Also, is your method superior in any way to what mahmoud has suggested?